# XML HTTP Request session gets closed before file download is done

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, openshift, wsgi, chromium

I try to build a web app that sends some videos to the user using XML HTTP Requests.

When the videos are small (~100KB) it works fine, but when they are larger (~5MB), the HTTP session often gets closed before the transfer is done.

Chromium shows the following error message:

```
GET http://mysite.rhcloud.com/myvideo.mp4 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

The server (Openshift free service) shows the following error:

```
[error] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] mod_wsgi (pid=XXX): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/XXX/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py'.
[error] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] IOError: failed to write data
```

The problem only reproduces when the server is remote, when I run the server locally (using wsgiref.simple_server) it works well.

In Wireshark I can see that the browser (Chromium on Linux Mint 32 bit) sends TCP FIN to the server before the video download is complete.

The server is an WSGI app which is written in Python and sends the videos like this:

```
ctype = 'video/mp4'
fixed_path = fix_path(environ['PATH_INFO'][1:])
file_size = os.stat(fixed_path).st_size
response_headers = [('Content-Type', ctype), ('Content-Length', str(file_size))]
start_response(status, response_headers)
return send_file_in_chunks(fixed_path)
```

where send_file_in_chunks is a generator:

```
def send_file_in_chunks(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as file_to_send:
        while True:
            chunk = file_to_send.read(10000)
            if chunk == '':
                break
            yield chunk
```

This is the client code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', path, true);
req.responseType = 'blob';
req.addEventListener('load', myHandler);
req.onerror = function() {}
req.send();
```

**Edit:**

I found a workaround that causes the problem to happen less frequently - sleep for several seconds (using setTimeout) before sending each new request. So maybe this issue is somehow related to the concurrent AJAX requests limit.

Comment: What is the ``Timeout`` directive set to in the Apache configuration? Are you using embedded or daemon mode of mod_wsgi?

Comment: I see a `WSGIDaemonProcess` line in the configuration files, so if I undserstand correctly it means I use the daemon mode.
`Timeout` is set to 5. I tried to change it but the file is read only.

Comment: I would regard the value for ``Timeout`` as being too low. This means the connection will be dropped if sending of data blocks for just 5 seconds. Any sort of network issues between client and server could easily trigger that, especially if operating over a mobile data network. Would suggest you read up on best practices around what to set ``Timeout`` value to.